# Adding resizable element in between sortable list JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I guess this is quite complex thing to do but that is what I need to achieve here. I'm struggeling with that a couple of days now. 
I'd like to have list which is sortable. Also when command key is pressed I'd like to use multiple selection so I could move more then one li element. And this works quite well. But there is another part of the task. In between list elements I need to have a resizable element, this is a li element as well with a class 'to-resize'. But as you can see in the fiddle js I prepared I encountered a lot of troubles with that part. I really do hope that you can help with that one guys.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/886030/

Expected result: to have exactly one break element between every two list elements. If you grab two elements with command(ctrl) key and move them then you'll see that there is no space between chosen two as expected.

```
 class Ratings {

 setChosenUsersList() {
 $('.users-list.multiple').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
     if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
     } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
     }
   });

   $('.users-list.multiple').sortable({
     items: "li",
     revert: 'true',
     update: this.createResizableElements,
     cursorAt: {
       left: 50,
       top: 45
     },
     helper: function (event, item) {
       if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
         item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
       }
       const helper = $("<li />");
       const elements = item.parent().children('.selected');
       const cloned = elements.clone();

       helper.append(cloned);
       elements.hide();
       item.data('multidrag', cloned);

       return helper;
     },
     stop: function (event, ui) {
       const cloned = ui.item.data("multidrag");

       ui.item.removeData("multidrag");
       ui.item.after(cloned);
       ui.item.siblings(":hidden").remove();
       ui.item.remove();
     },
   });
 }


 createResizableElements() {
 const sortableList = $('.users-list li');

   if (sortableList.length > 1) {
     $(sortableList).each(function (idx) {
       if (idx < sortableList.length - 1) {
         $(this).after('<li class="to-resize"></li>');
       }
     });
     $('.to-resize').resizable({
       minHeight: 1,
       minWidth: 320,
       maxHeight: 250,
       maxWidth: 320
     });
   }
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
        const ratings = new Ratings();
        ratings.setChosenUsersList();
});
```

Comment: Please specify the trouble you find, and the expected result.

Comment: Expected result: to have exactly one break element between every two list elements. If you grab two elements with command(ctrl) key and move them then you'll see that there is no space between chosen two as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the problem in multiple dragging, it is due to `stop` method.
Suppose we drag `item3`, `item4` between `item1` and `item2`
After the call to `createResizableElements` in `update` event, the list items status are

```
li item1
li resizable1
li item3
li resizable2
li item2
li resizable3
li item4
```

Since `item4` need to move after `item3`, in `stop` method, `*item3` and `*item4` is cloned and appended after `item3` and the orignal `item3` and `item4` are then removed, hence the list become

```
li item1
li resizable1
li *item3
li *item4
li resizable2
li item2
li resizable3
```

To solve this problem, just call `createResizableElements` in the end of `stop` method instead of `update` event. The changes is applied in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmqw17y6/1/).

Reference:[jQuery Sortable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-sort)